# Calling Java from Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, language-interoperability

When I try to run the following code (from the REPL) in Clojure:

```
(dotimes [i 5]
  (.start
   (Thread.
    (fn []
      (Thread/sleep (rand 1000))
      (println (format "Finished %d on %s" i (Thread/currentThread)))))))
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: i in this context
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: NO_SOURCE_FILE:6: Unable to resolve symbol: i in this context
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:3713)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works for me using the latest SVN (1144).

```
user> (dotimes [i 5] (.start (Thread. (fn [] (Thread/sleep (rand 1000)) (println (format "Finished %d on %s" i (Thread/currentThread)))))))

Finished 0 on Thread[Thread-16,5,main]
Finished 4 on Thread[Thread-20,5,main]
Finished 3 on Thread[Thread-19,5,main]
Finished 1 on Thread[Thread-17,5,main]
Finished 2 on Thread[Thread-18,5,main]
```

Are you using the September 16 release?  You almost have to use the SVN version of Clojure.  It's changing way too fast.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "Calling Java from Clojure". They are still [fiddling with the syntax](http://clojure.org/java_interop#toc14).